# jquery edit inplace

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit, edit

Hello all im new to jquery and im trying to make a edit inplace (simple)

but i dont know how to check if the users click on the edit submit bottom :b.

do you know a simple tutorial how to make a edit system :)?.

i have this now

```
$(function() {
    $('#forum_dato a').click(function()
    {
        //var data = $('#data').text();
        $('#data').html('<form action="..." method="post"><textarea name="data">' + 
                  $('#data').text() + 
                  '</textarea><input type="submit" value="Edit"></form>');
        return false;
    })
})
```

do i need to use some ajax or what is best :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the code someone else has already written? There are tons of libraries that already do this for you. Two really good ones:

- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) (yes, there's a jQuery plugin for it)
- [markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)

Save yourself the time and go write meaningful (read: value-added) code.

Comment: cause i dont think i need so much code just to do something that is so simple :)

Comment: @Sjmon: if it's so simple, then why do you need help with it? My point being: use the code that someone else has already put the time and energy into, and **move on**.

Answer (score 0):

This question already has been asked, and have decent answers IMO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708801/whats-the-best-edit-in-place-plugin-for-jquery

If it doesn't fit you need or have any other question, feel free to ask. :)

Comment: I would not recommend the jQuery Editable plugin @ that answer because it hasn't been updated for almost a year.

Comment: i dont want to use a plugin but i want to make it on my own :) its simple :d but i cant find out how is the best why to do it

Answer (score 0):

here you can find a nice plugin, maybe you can find some useful hints

[demosite](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html)
[doku](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

Comment: hm its to much code for me to look at, i just want some simple :d